# OSGI Unable to resolve root: failed to start bundle 'missing requirement' using javax.ws.rs : osgi.wiring.package

Tags: java, web-services, rest, maven, blueprint-osgi

I tried to start an OSGI REST bundle. i put the following import package :
`javax.ws.rs,
org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs,
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client,`

When I run the bundle I get the following error: 
 osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.ws.rs)(version>=2.0.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))"]]]

Comment: Sounds like a dependency issue. Can you the dependencies you are pulling in? Are you bringing in cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs and/or javax.ws.rs-api?

Comment: The data is incomplete. Can you put full logs and manifest.mf of your bundle ?

Answer (score 0):

**Step1**: check that you imported(runtime import) those packages into your bundle:

-if you are building your bundle using maven-bundle-plugin, in the pom.xml do like this:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
            <instructions>
              ...
              <Import-Package>
                javax.ws.rs*,
                org.codehaus.jackson*,
                org.apache.cxf.jaxrs*,
              </Import-Package>
              ...
           </instructions>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

- Unless, list those packages in the manifest.mf.

**Step 2:**
ckeck that those packages are well deployed in your container: provided or manually deployed in the container.
If using Apache Karaf, there is a feature called cxf-jaxrs => install/start it.